# Pub/Sub dumb question regarding publish and send

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

This should be obvious, but I cannot find anywhere in the Pub/Sub documentation to verify my guess:

- In GCP Pub/Sub, does the verb "publish" mean "for an originator to send to a Pub/Sub topic", and does the verb "send" mean "for Pub/Sub to send from a topic to the receiver in a subscription"?

The following summary statistics are provided "out of the box" by Pub/Sub, but I am not 100% sure what I'm looking at.

[image: Pub/Sub Publish/Send metrics]

If I am incorrect, please correct my understanding, or point me to some documentation.  I couldn't find anything to explain this super-basic definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These graphs each correspond to a metric available in Cloud Montioring:

- "Publish" is an aggregation over [`topic/message_sizes`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#pubsub/topic/message_sizes), which is the number of messages published.
- "Sent" corresponds to [`subscription/sent_message_count`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#pubsub/subscription/sent_message_count), which is the number of messages sent by Pub/Sub to the subscribers.
- "Ack" corresponds to [`subscription/ack_message_count`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#pubsub/subscription/ack_message_count), which is the number of messages acknowledged by subscribers.

Comment: Thanks!  So it sounds like my assumption was correct:  Publish ==> arriving in pubsub topic, Sent ==> arriving in subscribers, Ack ==> arriving *back* in pubsub